# Add fields in n-th element of an array in MongoDB

Tags: pymongo

I have the following document:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(some_mongodb_url)
coll = client.my_database.my_collection

coll.find_one( { '_id': 1 } )

{
    '_id': 1,
    'items_list': [
        {
            'item_id': 'one',
            'size': 1
        },
        {
            'item_id': 'two',
            'size': 2,
            'color': 'blue'
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to update the document adding the property `'color': 'red'` to the 0-nth item of the array, and changing its `size` to `2`.

I've tried with:

```
added_properties = {
    'item_id': 'one',
    'size': 2,
    'color': 'red'
}

coll.update_one( { '_id': 1 }, [ { '$addFields': { 'items_list.0': added_properties } } ], upsert=False)
```

But this produces a wrong result:

```
coll.find_one( { '_id': 1 } )

{'_id': 1,
 'items_list': [{'item_id': 'one',
   'size': 1,
   '0': {'item_id': 'one', 'size': 1, 'color': 'red'}},
  {'item_id': 'two',
   'size': 2,
   'color': 'blue',
   '0': {'item_id': 'one', 'size': 1, 'color': 'red'}}]}
```

The expected result would be:

```
{
    '_id': 1,
    'items_list': [
        {
            'item_id': 'one',
            'size': 2,
            'color': 'red'
        },
        {
            'item_id': 'two',
            'size': 2,
            'color': 'blue'
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update using this code add the property 'color': 'red' to the 0th item of the array, and change its size to 2.

```js
query = { '_id': 1 }
update = { '$set': { 'items_list.0.color': 'red', 'items_list.0.size': 2 } }

coll.update_one(query, update)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible approach I've found:

```
document = coll.find_one( { '_id': 1 } )

for idx, item in enumerate(document['items_list']):
    if idx == 0: # update only the 0-nth element
        updated_item = document['items_list'][idx] | added_properties
        coll.update_one( { '_id': 1 }, { '$set': { f"items_list.{idx}": updated_item } }, upsert=False)
```